# Java - checking multiple JTextFields with keytyped action

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 swing text fields and a swing button. What i want to do is to change button.setEnabled() from false to true when there is none of those 3 fields blank. I suppose it's not really difficult, but i just can't find a way to do it.
It's easy to have button.setEnabled(true) on keytyped action of one text field, but how do i check all of them?
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way: wherever you would put `button.setEnabled(true)` put something like

```
button.setEnabled(!tf1.getText().isEmpty() && !tf2.getText().isEmpty() && !tf3.getText().isEmpty());
```

Comment: That's good for one point in time, but you'd still want to attach that to some listener, right?

Comment: Yeah, to all the `DocumentListener`s, just as you've done. Sorry my answer was a bit too brief.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to check for just keyboard input as you want to also account for copy and paste input ***and*** removal (deactivate the JButton). I'd use one DocumentListener for all three of the field's associated Documents and then set the button to enabled if all documents contain text.

For example,

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class FieldListenerTest {
   private static final int FIELD_COUNT = 5;

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JButton button = new JButton("Button");
      FieldListener fieldListener = new FieldListener(button);
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_COUNT; i++) {
         JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
         fieldListener.registerDoc(field.getDocument());
         mainPanel.add(field);
      }
      button.setEnabled(false);
      mainPanel.add(button);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FieldListenerTest");
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class FieldListener implements DocumentListener {
   private List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
   private JButton button;

   public FieldListener(JButton button) {
      this.button = button;
   }

   public void registerDoc(Document doc) {
      docs.add(doc);
      doc.addDocumentListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      update();
   }

   @Override
   public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      update();
   }

   @Override
   public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      update();
   }

   private void update() {
      for (Document doc : docs) {
         if (doc.getLength() == 0) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
            return;
         }
      }
      button.setEnabled(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: that must be done on EDT, only Listener can do that, Document +1

Comment: Thanks. Coupling needs to be reduced though.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

Create a single anonymous listener that checks if fields are blank and sets the button state accordingly (eg):

```
     DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { 
           updateButton();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           updateButton();
        } 

        private void updateButton() {
           boolean all_blank = tf1.getText().isEmpty() && 
                               tf2.getText().isEmpty() &&
                               tf3.getText().isEmpty();
           button.setEnabled(!all_blank);
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           updateButton();
        }
     };
```

And then attach it to all of the fields:

```
tf1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
tf2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
tf3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
```

Note: As Eng.Fouad mentioned, KeyListener does not fire with paste, so I've changed it to a DocumentListener